# Highlight radius in OpenLayers 2

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to create a highlight control which will highlight a line, it should highlight the line when the cursor is near this line (e.g. ~10px) and when cursor is pointing to line. I have following code, but it only works if I put cursor directly on drawn line.

```
highlightCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([routesLayer], {
            hover: true,
            highlightOnly: true,
            eventListeners: {
                featurehighlighted: HighLightRoute,
                featureunhighlighted: unHighLightRoute
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution:**

- Add new layer that will draw the same vector line, features should have higher `strokeWidth` than original layer, `strokeOpacity`should be equal to zero (becauseit should be invisible for user)
- Add this new invisible layer to highlightCtrl